# Change between view controllers automatically (xcode 9)

Tags: ios, swift

I've been trying to get this code but no look yet. 
I need to move between my first view controller and my second view controller (view controller 2) after 3 seconds. 
It sounds simple but I can't find a simple answer!
Thank you to anyone who can help

Comment: Please show me the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime, execute: DispatchWorkItem)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue)
Something like:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+3) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "myViewcontroller2", sender: nil)
}
```

or

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+3) {
    self.present(myViewController2, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Perfect thanks Dennis, the first option worked, make sure you call the segue "myViewcontroller2"